# Liquibase H2 create sequence failed with bigint

Tags: h2, liquibase

Using liquibase 3.8.9, running following changeset success:

```
<changeSet author="quarkus" id="1-1">
        <createSequence cacheSize="1" cycle="false" incrementBy="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="1" schemaName="myschema" sequenceName="mytable_id_seq" startValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
```

and adding data type bigint specification fail:

```
<changeSet author="quarkus" id="1-1">
    <createSequence cacheSize="1" cycle="false" dataType="bigint" incrementBy="1" maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="1" schemaName="myschema" sequenceName="mytable_id_seq" startValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
```

Stack trace

```
ERROR: Failed to start application
java.lang.IllegalStateException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db-test/changelog-0.xml::1-1::quarkus:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE SEQUENCE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE_ID_SEQ AS[*] BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807"; SQL statement:
CREATE SEQUENCE myschema.mytable_id_seq AS bigint START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 [42000-200] [Failed SQL: (42000) CREATE SEQUENCE myschema.mytable_id_seq AS bigint START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807]
```

Is there a limitation with bigint data type?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the exception with stack trace or error message you receive?

Comment: [According to the H2 manual](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_sequence)  sequences are always created with bigint and there is [no option](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#sequence_options) to change it

Comment: This means that liquibase should ignore **dataType="bigint"** instruction.

Answer (score 4):

As your exception says, there's an error in SQL syntax.

```
[42000-200] [Failed SQL: (42000) 
CREATE SEQUENCE myschema.mytable_id_seq AS bigint START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
```

I believe it's because of the reserved word `bigint`. Perhaps it's a bug in Liquibase's mechanism of creation of SQL queries. I tried executing your changeSet on my local environment, and got the same error.

So I've removed `dataType="bigint"` from the changeSet and it worked.

```
<changeSet author="quarkus" id="1-1">
    <createSequence cacheSize="1" cycle="false" incrementBy="1"
                    maxValue="9223372036854775807" minValue="1" schemaName="public"
                    sequenceName="mytable_id_seq" startValue="1"/>
</changeSet>
```

After some Liquibase source code debugging, I've found the SQL query that's being generated for this changeSet:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE_ID_SEQ 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
MINVALUE 1 
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
```

And as was mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name in the comments, the dataType is `bigint` by default.